# Programmatically access visual studio query results pane from add in

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

Is there a way to access visual studio's query results pane from Addin?

I am not referring to query window from Menu - Data - Transact SQL Editor - new query. I am thinking from Server explore - expand some database - expand tables, right click on table and choose new query. After you select what tables will be included, check couple of columns and choose execute. New window will open. That window is Document class I know, but not able to get contents of controls or pane's or even panels from that class. At the bottom you can see a pane with rows and columns.

I need to access that pane or grid control if it's possible. Or even better somehow over reflection to retrieve a cell value of a selected cell in that query results window?

I already built addin for VS, but having trouble to retrieve cell's value from that grid. Tried with reflection but cannot get to the bottom of the problem which or even where this pane or grid control is.

Answer (score 0):

```
    private static IEnumerable<IntPtr> GetChildWindows(IntPtr parent)
    {
        List<IntPtr> result = new List<IntPtr>();
        GCHandle listHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(result);
        try
        {
            NativeMethods.EnumWindowProc childProc = new NativeMethods.EnumWindowProc(EnumWindow);
            NativeMethods.EnumChildWindows(parent, childProc, GCHandle.ToIntPtr(listHandle));
        }
        finally
        {
            if(listHandle.IsAllocated)
            {
                listHandle.Free();
            }
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Callback method to be used when enumerating windows.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">Handle of the next window</param>
    /// <param name="pointer">Pointer to a GCHandle that holds a reference to the list to fill</param>
    /// <returns>True to continue the enumeration, false to bail</returns>
    private static bool EnumWindow(IntPtr handle, IntPtr pointer)
    {
        GCHandle gch = GCHandle.FromIntPtr(pointer);
        List<IntPtr> list = gch.Target as List<IntPtr>;
        if(list == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("GCHandle Target could not be cast as List<IntPtr>");
        }

        list.Add(handle);

        // You can modify this to check to see if you want to cancel the operation, then return a null here
        return true;
    }

private DataGridView Grid()
{
IEnumerable<IntPtr> a = GetChildWindows(handle);
            foreach(IntPtr b in a)
        {
            Control c = Control.FromHandle(b);
            if(c == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            try
            {
                if(c.Name != "DataGridView")
                {
                    continue;
                }

                DataGridView dv = c as DataGridView;
                if(dv != null)
                {
                    return dv;
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // It is safe to suppress errors here.
            }
        }
```

}